# How to serve html/php in nginx location

Tags: php, html, nginx

Heyo, front end guy moving website from shared hosting to SPA droplet. I have a Headless CMS in /build, a Node SendGrid Mailserver in /mail, and am trying to have some html and php in /wp-content/themes/webdev/projects/trackjob/point_card/. (it's a php proxy) The reason is an old client used an iframe to this url from my old site and its just best to copy it over.

The card_api_js_v2.html will need to make an AJAX request to a php file in the same parent directory.

I am just getting more familiar with nginx. Advice?

Currently, I have this...

```
location / {
   root /var/www/build;
   try_files $uri $uri/ /;
}

location /mail {
   root /var/www/server;
   proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; 
   proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

// DOESNT WORK ??? 
location /wp-content/themes/webdev/projects/trackjob/point_card/ {
   root /var/www/wp-content/themes/webdev/projects/trackjob/point_card;  
   try_files $uri $uri/ /card_api_js_v2.html;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding on how the `root` directive works. When you use this location block

```
location /wp-content/themes/webdev/projects/trackjob/point_card/ {
   root /var/www/wp-content/themes/webdev/projects/trackjob/point_card;
   try_files $uri $uri/ /card_api_js_v2.html;
}
```

and got a `/wp-content/themes/webdev/projects/trackjob/point_card/card_api_js_v2.html` incoming request, nginx concatenates the **$document_root** (which is `/var/www/wp-content/themes/webdev/projects/trackjob/point_card`) and **$uri** (which is `/wp-content/themes/webdev/projects/trackjob/point_card/card_api_js_v2.html`) variables and searches for the file `/var/www/wp-content/themes/webdev/projects/trackjob/point_card/wp-content/themes/webdev/projects/trackjob/point_card/card_api_js_v2.html` (which is obviously would not be found). This is the main difference between the [`root`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) and [`alias`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) nginx directives. Your location block should be the

```
location /wp-content/themes/webdev/projects/trackjob/point_card/ {
   root /var/www;  
   try_files $uri $uri/ /wp-content/themes/webdev/projects/trackjob/point_card/card_api_js_v2.html;
}
```

instead.

**Update**

If you need to serve the PHP scripts inside this location, change it to

```
location ^~ /wp-content/themes/webdev/projects/trackjob/point_card/ {
   root /var/www;  
   try_files $uri $uri/ /wp-content/themes/webdev/projects/trackjob/point_card/card_api_js_v2.html;
   location ~ \.php$ {
      include fastcgi.conf;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
      # if your php-fpm listens to the UNIX socket (assuming default socket path)
      # fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock
      # if your php-fpm listens to the TCP/IP port (assuming default port)
      # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
   }
}
```

Comment: OHHHHH.... well thank you let me go try this now.Combined with IVO's answer I think this will do the trick. I am starting to understand this better thank you!

Comment: Okay so here is one follow up question I need to route it differently if the request is to a php file. So for example this ajax request needs to work... URL/wp-content/themes/webdev/projects/trackjob/point_card/card_proxy.php?oncard=000000000000000

Comment: That ajax request is made from the html card_api_js_v2.html file and it goes to a file called card_proxy.php. Is this just a matcher difference or can I actually put the exact file name in the main location directory and create an additional one?

Comment: @MichaelPaccione Check the update to the answer. Do not miss the `^~` after the `location` keyword or each request for the PHP script will be processed by your primary PHP handler location.

Comment: Hmmm I seem to get a 502 error on this. This is the github gist: https://gist.github.com/mpaccione/c12069cd32de5ac587d70b56283dd722

Comment: @MichaelPaccione Do you actually have PHP-FPM service running? What port/socket is it listening? Can you show your `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf` file from nginx config directory?

Comment: Seems legit? https://gist.github.com/mpaccione/72c0555688a5a59523dee765b0bd8ecc  ...  I have php-fpm7.4 active and running.

Comment: @MichaelPaccione You didn't answer what socket or port it is listening. Lets simplify things a little, try an updated answer, uncomment one of the `fastcgi_pass` directives and correct the socket path or port number if needed.

Comment: Okay, I should have been using incognito. It kinda tricked me LOL. It works thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

In order to actually run the PHP files (rather than sending their content as text to the browser) you will need to use PHP-FPM:

```
        location ~ \.php(/|$) {
            try_files $uri =444;

            fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
            fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
            fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
            fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
 
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO          $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https;
            fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
            fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
            fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
            fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
 
            fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
            fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    custom;
 
            fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
            fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
            fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
            fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
            fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_connect_timeout 120;
            fastcgi_send_timeout 600;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
            fastcgi_buffering off;
            fastcgi_request_buffering off;
            fastcgi_buffers 8 128k;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
            fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
            fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_ignore_client_abort off;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful :) I am wondering if you look back at the original question is there a fix for the location settings that doesn't work.